# Elasticsearch: Find documents with any object property greater than 0

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to search any document that fits this criteria:

Documents indexed:

```
{id:1,stock:{1123:4,1124:12,1125:15}}
{id:2,stock:{1454:12,1455:0}}
{id:3,stock:{}}
{id:4,stock:{2544:0,2545:0}}
```

I want to find documents with any stock property greater than 0, the matched documents shoud be 1 and 2.

It seems simple but I didn't found any successful way of doind this whithout scripting.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many fields do you have in your index `stocks`?

Having many fields leads to a huge mapping and this is why the solution proposed by Andrei Stefan is slow. Worst, if you have an increasing number of properties, the mapping will get bigger and bigger and may lead to a crash of your cluster, it is called a [mapping explosion](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-crash-elasticsearch#mapping-explosion)

The proper way to store arrays who contains a lot of different keys is like this, with a [nested mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-mapping.html):

```
stock: [
    {"key": 1123, "value": 4}
    {"key": 1124, "value": 12}
    {"key": 1125, "value": 15}
]
```

With this data structure, it is quite obvious to build the requested query (search for stock.value>0 using a [nested filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/query-dsl-nested-query.html)). However changing the mapping to nested will force you to reindex your data and adapt some of your current queries.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": [
        "stock.*"
      ],
      "query": "{0 TO *]"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm doing a faceted search, all with bool queries and I missed that a full text query could do the job. Thank you!

Comment: Finally I can't use this query because is slow as hell, from time resposes from my api like 200ms now I'm getting 5s

Comment: :-) hehe, then don't use arbitrary sub-fields for `stock` and define your own and put in place a rule for your users to use those and not pick whatever name for that. Still, this is not the entire reason for the slowness and it can depend on a wide range of factors.